# SSE intrinsics atan2

Tags: c++, trigonometry, simd, sse, intrinsics

I need a very fast `atan2` for getting the gradient out of the sobel values (I'm implementing canny edge algo.). Does anyone know a very fast implementation, preferable in intrinsics (SIMD) or a very fast approximation. (I think an approximation is enough, because the values are rounded to 0°, 45°, 90°, 135°)

ADD: I'm aware of Intel's IPP atan2 in SVML unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: If you're rounding to only a few angle values, just check the sign of the arguments and compare the ratio of their magnitude against known thresholds.

Comment: Why do you think that `std::atan2()` is slow? Have you measured its CPU time? Have you looked at the disassembly which C++ compiler generates in Release mode? Isn't `atan2` already a single FPU instruction?

Comment: Slow is a point of view. First std::atan2 is over accurate for my purpose and it don't use simd instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to round to an octant number, presumably from `-22.5°` to `337.5°` in `45°` increments.

The octants are separated by four lines through the origin with equation

```
Y = X tan(Θ),
```

or

```
a.Y - b.X = 0.
```

with suitable scaling factors.

By computing the signs of these expressions for the four desired angles, you will find the octant. By a clever combination, you can limit to three sign evaluations, as there are `8=2³` possibilities.

It is likely that this can be evaluated with SIMD instructions by computing the discriminant expressions, their signs, and suitable combinations of their signs, but this isn't trivial.

Probably a conversion to a multiple of 45° isn't necessary, not even a sequential numbering. It all depends on what you do with the octant information.

---

Additional SIMD suggestion:

With preloaded coefficients, you can compute all four line equations in a single go for an (X, Y) pair, using 16 bits integer arithmetic (possibly with multiply-and-add). Then get the signs and pack them to four bits with `_mm_movemask_epi8`. Use the four bit value as input to a small lookup table.

Comment: @user1235183: check the addendum.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/4261/) `atan2()` is already a single FPU instruction: x87 FPU opcode `FPATAN`. Just look at the disassembly your compiler generates when you call `std::atan2()`. If it is not that single FPU instruction, then you can try [this](https://gist.github.com/tobin/2028637) in GCC inline assembly:

```
inline double my_atan2 (double y, double x) { 
  double result; 
  asm (
     "fpatan\n\t" 
     : "=t" (result)       // outputs; t = top of fpu stack
     : "0" (x),            // inputs; 0 = same as result
       "u" (y)             //         u = 2nd floating point register
     );   
  return result; 
}
```

Comment: The latency of FPATAN can be 150 cycles or more.

Comment: Most math-library implementations don't use `fpatan` because you can do better without it.  Also, getting data between XMM registers and the x87 stack is slow, and this only does one `atan2` result at a time.  Future readers, see http://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables.